# Android XMPP client does not connect to Openfire server

Tags: android, localhost, xmpp, openfire, messenger

I have configured openfire server on my laptop running windows7. Pandion and Spark desktop clients are working fine on the localhost. Tested it thoroughly with multiple users.

Laptop is connected to a wifi network.
I am trying to connect to the localhost openfire from Xabber client installed on Samsung galaxy pop running Android OS. Mobile is connected to the same wifi network.

```
http://localhost:9090/login.jsp?url=%2Findex.jsp 

I am able to access this admin url in mobile browser.
```

But none of the xmpp clients are able to connect to localhost openfire.
Configuration done-
server- localhost
port- 5222

username and password are exactly same as provided in Spark desktop client.

It would be great to know if someone has the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use localhost in the android client to connect to your laptop. And i do not believe that using localhost in an android browser would connect to a server on your laptop. You have to use the local ip address of the server to connect. Often something like 192.168.#.#.